# <pip3 package> command not found on zsh but found on bash

Tags: python, django, bash, pip, zsh

I installed django on my Ubuntu 16.04 using `pip3 install django`. But when I type `django-admin` and hit enter I get `command not found`. I even verified using:

```
import django
print(django.get_version())
```

I use zshell instead of bash. At first I thought this is a django issue. So I installed another pip3 package `virtualenv`. I then typed `virtualenv` on terminal and hit enter, same output: `command not found`.

Then I was sure this is a shell issue. So I changed my shell back to bash and both `django-admin` and `virtuaenv` commands were found.

How can I get zsh to discover the pip3 packages?

Comment: Assuming you're not already using the venv functionality built into python, most likely there's something in your `.bashrc` or other bash-specific file that sets relevant environment variables that you need to do from a zsh-specific profile (or one that's shared by both shells).

Comment: @Eisenheim Can you do `echo $PATH` in both shells and paste the result? Neither file you pasted seemed to contain anything relevant.

Comment: Maybe also paste `~/.zprofile`, `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.profile`

Comment: That's a handful of profiles to paste. As a temporary solution I am directly adding `$HOME/.local/bin` to my $PATH, because that's where `django-admin` resides (as shown by `which django-admin`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned, your Python package executables are installed to `~/.local/bin`. If you check `$PATH` in `bash`, you will find it contains that path. In the default Ubuntu 16.04 installation, this is done in `~/.profile`. `zsh` does not execute this file, however, and so probably does not have `~/.local/bin` in its `$PATH`. The solution as you have found is to add it: this can be done automatically by modifying your `.zshrc`, e.g.

```
export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: That's what I did, with doubt and hesitation -_- But now I am sure haven't done anything wrong.